# ValueError: Error code 'I2041' supplied to 'ignore' option does not match '^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{0,3}$'

Tags: python, flake8

Upon importing this [flake8 plugin](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-import-restrictions/) `flake8-import-restrictions==1.1.1`, I've notice this error appeared. I tried ignoring it by adding it to my setup.cfg file ignore option as shown below.

```py
[isort]
force_single_line=True
ensure_newline_before_comments = True
single_line_exclusions=[]
line_length = 100
src_paths = myproject,tests
skip= .gitignore, .env
skip_glob=env/*, spec/*
profile=google
lexicographical=True
order_by_type=True
color_output=True


[flake8]
ignore = D413, E203, E266, E501, E711, F401, F403, I2041, W503
max-line-length = 100
max-complexity = 18
application-import-names = myproject,tests
import-order-style = google
exclude = tests/integration/.env.shadow, env

[pylint]
max-line-length = 100

[pylint.messages_control]
disable = C0330, C0326
```

However, flake8 appears to not like this ignore option:

```py
  File "/Users/gree030/Workspace/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/options/config.py", line 131, in parse_config
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Error code 'I2041' supplied to 'ignore' option does not match '^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{0,3}$'
```

## What I have Tried

- uninstalling the plugin to verify it's that particular plugin

Of course to not see this error would mean I would have to uninstall the plugin. However, I would really like to use this flake8 plugin. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Interesting regex `^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{0,3}$` can't match `I2041` because `{0,3}` says it can match from 0 to 3 digits e.g. ABC123 but `I2041` have 4 digits. So seems like that either `I2041` or the regex in source code is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flake8 does not support 4 digit codes -- before this used to silently "work" but would fail in many situations surprisingly.

in flake8 6.0 the silent failure was upgraded to a noisy failure.  the plugin in question should adapt its error code structure to match the expected code structure (usually 1-3 letters followed by 3 numbers)

this is a problem with that particular plugin and not with flake8 itself

---

disclaimer: I'm the flake8 maintainer